# when build my project in flutter , I get the following error

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

The Error showing like this...i couldn't understand the actual problem.

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\ajmal\OneDrive\Desktop\Flutter projects\Firebase project -week16\chatapp\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2bc53116d09bd81691d0c1eb73277574\kernel_snapshot.d

: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:5
import 'dart:html';      
       ^
Error: Type 'WebSocket' not found.
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:12
  WebSocket? socket;
  ^^^^^^^^^
: Error: 'WebSocket' isn't a type.
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:12
  WebSocket? socket;
  ^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The method 'WebSocket' isn't defined for the class 'BaseWebSocket'.
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:38
- 'BaseWebSocket' is from 'package:get/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart' ('../../../../Documents/flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.5/lib/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart').
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebSocket'.
      socket = WebSocket(url);
               ^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'WebSocket' isn't defined for the class 'BaseWebSocket'.
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:105
- 'BaseWebSocket' is from 'package:get/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart' ('../../../../Documents/flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.5/lib/get_connect/sockets/src/sockets_html.dart').
package:get/…/src/sockets_html.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'WebSocket'.
    if (socket != null && socket!.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {

                                                ^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:652:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:792:21)

<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:615:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1433:12)
<asynchronous suspension>

5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\ajmal\OneDrive\Documents\flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\ajmal\OneDrive\Documents\flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

 Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to import `dart:html` (direct import or transitive import from a library) but it is not supported.

If you are not building a web application, you cannot import `dart:html` as it is only available on web (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-html/dart-html-library.html).

If it is from your code, you can give [`universal_html`](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) a try as it is supported on io platforms. But some features might not be available and you might hit a `UnsuportedError` at runtime. But at least it will build.